# Django can't edit user profile

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make an edit user profile form, my problem is if i don't exclude the user from form it will ask for it, but if i exclude it i'm getting:

Error:

```
IntegrityError at /apps/edit-profile
null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (21, 85.75, Alexe, Bogdan, null, Romania, null, null, null, null).
```

models.py

```
    class UserProfile(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
        balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, default=0.00, blank=True, null=True)
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
        last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
```

forms.py

```
class UserProfileForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ('user', )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def user_profile(request):
    data = dict()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        profile = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, user=request.user)
        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            profile = form.save(commit=False)
            profile.balance = Income.objects.filter(assigned_to__username=request.user).aggregate(sum=Sum('value'))['sum']
            profile.save()
            return redirect('/apps/home')
    else:
        form = UserProfileForm()
    data['form'] = form
    return render(request, 'core/profile.html', data)
```

profile.html

```
<form class="js-validation-bootstrap" action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.errors }}
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-lg-4 col-form-label" for="val-username">First Name </label>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <input type="Text" class="form-control" id="val-username" name="first_name" placeholder="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-lg-4 col-form-label" for="val-username">Last Name </label>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <input type="Text" class="form-control" id="val-username" name="last_name" placeholder="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 ml-auto">
        <button type="Submit" class="btn btn-alt-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

I don't understand why it gives me that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add current user in your view like this even if this field excluded:

```
profile = form.save(commit=False)
profile.user = request.user
profile.save()
```

Comment: if i try this i'm getting this:        duplicate key value violates unique constraint "core_userprofile_user_id_key"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(1) already exists.

Comment: @NitaAlexandru looks like current user already have profile. You need to check this first and pass existing profile to the form as `instance` argument. `profile=get_object_or_404(UserProfile, user=user)   form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=profile)`

Comment: @NitaAlexandru Can you post updated code and full error traceback?

Comment: Try this `form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=profile)` profile should be key word argument `instance=profile`.

Comment: jesus christ thanks alot, but can you explain alittle more detailed why i was getting those erros?

Comment: and btw, do i have to exclude user from form?

Comment: @NitaAlexandru the main reason of this error is that onetoone field should be unique. So if profile already exists for selected user(your case) database raise errror. To fix this you need first of all obtain existing profile. And pass this profile to form. In other words with this little fix you are not creating new profile but updating existing one.

Comment: @NitaAlexandru yes you can exclude it from form.

Comment: aha, so everytime it was trying to create another profile with the same user, but it wasn't allowing it, btw you should update your answer so other can see aswell :)